# Rational behind having parent id of nested resources in RESTful URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, url, restful-url

Given the following URL design for a nested resources in a RESTful API:

```
/magazines/:magazine_id/ads/:id POST
```

What's the rational behind having the magazine id in there **given that the ads id uniquiely identifies ads across magazines**?

Besides that it looks maybe nicer when presenting the user with that URL or simply convention. Is there any deeper meaning or constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this depends very much on who is developing. In theory, there's no need.

In fact, Rails Guides show this in the [2.7.2 Section (Shallow Nesting)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), that you can nest the resources only when they don't have an id:

```
 resources :articles do
   resources :comments, only: [:index, :new, :create]
 end
 resources :comments, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Or in your case:

```
 resources :magazines do
   resources :ads, only: [:index, :new, :create]
 end
 resources :ads, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 0):

> given that the ads id uniquiely identifies ads across magazines?

This is the most common convention, but not a universal one.  You are free to override `to_param` in your model and violate the universality-by-database-primary-key convention.  Imagine that you also did this for magazines (e.g. for SEO purposes).  In this case, including the magazine ID/slug in the route might be quite necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what "shallow" does:

```
resources :magazines do   
  resources :ads, shallow: true 
end
```

means exactly the same as

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
resources :ads, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

See section 2.7.2 Shallow Nesting in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html